# How do I video screen capture with windows 10?

Tags: screen-capture, video-capture

How do I single screen capture with windows 10 for making programming tutorials?

Comment: Where have you looked for information before posting here? What research have you done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Snagit or Camtasia. Alternatively Windows 10 has a built-in screen capture tool. Heres how:

1. Locate and run the Xbox app
2. With the Xbox app running, jump to the app you want to record and press the 'Windows' key with the letter 'G' (Win + G) to open the Game Bar.
3. Tell the Xbox recording app that you want to open the Game Bar by telling it you want to record a game.
4. Once the Game Bar is loaded choose your action, either Screenshot (for a single image capture) or Start Recording (for capturing video).

Comment: Will it work between different screens?

Comment: I am unsure, probably

Comment: Free...http://camstudio.org/

Comment: Software recommendations are frowned upon here as answers, that is why it us a comment.

Comment: That rule is stupid and pointless, and it's not applicable here. This is a legitimate question and the answer about using the BUILT IN XBox "Game Bar" is a **legitimate** answer that requires no 3rd party software!